# How to dynamicaly change Table height after binding in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, dynamic, height, xamarin, cell

I am facing issue with xamarin.ios UI Design. I am trying to design, inside tableview different size of cell height .

How to calculate cell height based content . Pls reply ASPS

Answer (score 1):

In your Table's Source class, use

```
public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

to determine the height of each cell.  *How* you figure out how tall a cell should be will depend on the design of your cell and what data you're placing inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {


        return yourHeight;
    }
```